# "About..." page on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ui-design

I'm asking all those who have apps in the Apple iPhone App Store. Do you have an "About..." window/page/view in your app, or do you rely on iTunes for providing the developer info to the customer? If the former, where's the button/link to that? Real estate is so precious on the iPhone screen, I cannot think of some space I can waste for an "About..." button without it sticking like a sore thumb.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add your "about" info into the system settings for your app so that it's there but not directly in the app.  I have an app with no about page, but it's because the target users are children so there's no point.  For other apps, I might add a page into the app -- it all depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the little (i) icon thats found in the corner of a lot of apps, the native weather app comes to mind. It uses minimal space, too.

I plan on adding about sections to most apps I create.